# Unit testing for Python function that checks whether a value is in a range

Tags: python, unit-testing

This is the first time I've ever tried to write unit tests before, so I wanted to post here to see if I'm doing it "right". I read a couple of articles on the subject, but I work alone so I want to ensure that I fully understand the standard ideas before continuing. Could you please take a look at this and let me know what you think?

Here's an example method:

```
def is_in_range(value: float,
                allowed_range: (float, float),
                inclusive: bool = True) -> bool:
    """Checks if the given value falls within the allowed range.

    Raises:
        ValueError: If value or range are non numeric.
    """
    if float(allowed_range[0]) != allowed_range[0] or float(
            allowed_range[1]) != allowed_range[1] or float(value) != value:
        raise ValueError("Inputs must be numeric.")

    if inclusive:
        return min(allowed_range) <= value <= max(allowed_range)
    else:
        return min(allowed_range) < value < max(allowed_range)
```

And here are the unit tests I wrote:

```
class Test_IsInRange(object):
    def test_in_range(self):
        value = 4
        surrounding_range = (value-1, value+1)
        assert utilities.is_in_range(value, surrounding_range)

    def test_out_range(self):
        value = 76
        not_surrounding_range = (value+1, value+2)
        assert not utilities.is_in_range(value, not_surrounding_range)

    def test_exclusive_range(self):
        value = 23
        inclusive_range = (value, value+10)
        assert not utilities.is_in_range(value, inclusive_range, inclusive=False)

    def test_inclusive_range(self):
        value = 1003
        inclusive_range = (value-500, value)
        assert utilities.is_in_range(value, inclusive_range, inclusive=True)

    def test_string(self):
        string_input = "tt"
        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
            utilities.is_in_range(string_input, ("a","zzz"))
```

Am I testing properly? Am I testing too many different cases? Too few? Should I combine or separate any tests?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, do you want a review of just the unit-tests or are you happy for people to critique `is_in_range` too?

Comment: Thanks! I'm mostly looking for input on the unit tests but other feedback is welcome too.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your tests.  You definitely don't have too many.  You actually could have too few.  Consider:

In one dimension, you have 5 cases you can check:

- `val < min`
- `val == min`
- `min < val < max`
- `val == max`
- `val > max`

In another dimension, you have `inclusive=True` and `inclusive=False`.  That makes at least 10 combinations you should test.  You also have a "inclusive uses the default" which could add 5 more.

Then, you have `allowed_range` which expects a `tuple` with limits in either order.  So you should test `allowed_range=(1.5, 5.1)` separate from `allowed_range=(5.1, 1.5)`.  That would further double the number of tests.

What about tests where `min == max`, using both inclusive and non-inclusive limits?

You don't need to write separate functions for each test; each function can easily perform a suite of several tests:

```
def test_unequal_limits(self):
    #          val, min, max, incl,  excl
    tests = [ (1.5, 2.5, 5.5, False, False),
              (2.5, 2.5, 5.5, True,  False),
              (3.5, 2.5, 5.5, True,  True),
              (5.5, 2.5, 5.5, True,  False),
              (6.5, 2.5, 5.5, False, False) ]
    for val, lower, upper, incl, excl in tests:
          assert is_in_range(val, (lower, upper)) == incl
          assert is_in_range(val, (lower, upper), False) == excl
          assert is_in_range(val, (upper, lower)) == incl
          assert is_in_range(val, (upper, lower), False) == excl

def test_equal_limits(self):
    #          val, limit, incl
    tests = [ (1.5, 3.5,   False),
              (3.5, 3.5,   True),
              (5.5, 3.5,   False) ]
    for val, limit, incl in tests:
          assert is_in_range(val, (limit, limit)) == incl
          assert is_in_range(val, (limit, limit), False) == False
```

You test exactly one case where all inputs are non-numeric strings.  You probably need to test the minimum, maximum, and value separately.

---

Regarding your function `is_in_range()` function.

Why raise a `ValueError` when the input is considered to be "non-numeric"?  Without the non-numeric check, `is_in_range("tt", ("a","zzz"))` would return `True`, which would be quite acceptable.

The non-numeric check causes more problems:

```
>>> val = 1000000000000000000
>>> is_in_range(val, (val-1, val+1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 1, in <module>
    is_in_range(val, (val-1, val+1))
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 11, in is_in_range
    raise ValueError("Inputs must be numeric.")
ValueError: Inputs must be numeric.
```

Without the non-numeric check, the function would return `True`, as expected.

---

The parameter `allowed_range: (float, float)` has a type-hint of "tuple of two floats", but there is nothing in Python that will enforce that.  You can provide a more than 2 values.  `50` is not in the range of `1` to `10`, but it is in the range of `(1, 10, 100)` ... whatever that means!

```
>>> is_in_range(50, (1, 10, 100))
True
```

And you are only testing the first two values for numeric-ishness.  `0` is not in the range of `1` to `10`, but it is in the range of `[1, 10, False]`!

```
>>> is_in_range(0, [1, 10, False])
True
```

Comment: So there could be 30-50 tests for a simple function like this? At what point do you decide that there are "enough" tests? Ie, I could write a test for every single possible case but then there would be infinite tests. It seems like 300 lines of test code for a 10-line function would be excessive -- at that point, I'd be spending significantly more time writing tests than actually writing functional code.

Comment: Also thanks for the feedback on the function; I'll definitely take that into account.

Comment: For the record, I said "you ... **could** have too few."  I'd personally add more checks in each test.  `test_in_range_inclusive` would contain the 3 subtests (equal min, equal max, & between min & max), Each subtest could use another helper to test normal and reversed limits.  But I'd even go as far as having one test function with a list of test cases `[ (val, min, max, inclusive, expected), ...]`, loop over the test cases, and assert if result doesn't match expected, also checking reversed limits.  Then additional test function(s) for checking for expected exceptions when strings are given.

Comment: OK, thanks! I just realized my first comment may have come off as argumentative; I didn't mean to disagree. The question of how many unit tests I should have has been the sticking point that I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: No, you didn't come across argumentative. You asked if you had too many or too few tests. I answered that you could perform a lot more testing, but I never answered exactly how to do that.  You asked if you should combine tests; I never answered that at all. If the impression I left was that 300 lines of code *should* be written to test a 10-line function, that's my fault. Combining multiple tests into one function, and looping over test data allows many tests to be done with just a few lines of code.  I've updated my answer to include one way (not necessarily the right way) of doing that.

Comment: @Ian Number of test cases in practice is a matter of resources. What I find useful is to write a large number of test cases where user input is expected. For example, if you can modularize the code to make sure that your function only takes expected values, you reduce several test conditions. Another function whose job is to sanitize these values would have those test cases, but they will be lower since it does not have test the logic behind the test case.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that mostly two functions A and B would have lower number of total test cases that if you combine these two functions in a single one. It is matter of practicality on how to decompose the functions